# How to handle data types?

Tags: c, char

I'm really facing a problem with data types conversions.

I'm making a GUI version of a program with GTK. To get entry_text string I need a `const char*` which obliges me to use this data type in the function below.

I want to convert it to `string(char[])` and compiler keep giving me errors below :

Source code where errors come:

```
    //....
    char ret (const char *bd){
    char c[100];
    strcpy(c,bd);
    return *c;
}

char encode(const char ebuf[],const char epass[]) {
char *buf=ret(ebuf);
char *pass=ret(epass);
//...
```

When I compile the code I get following errors (with g++):

> codgui.cpp: In function ‘char encode(const char*, const char*)’:
>   codgui.cpp:36: error: invalid conversion from ‘char’ to ‘char*’
>   codgui.cpp:37: error: invalid conversion from ‘char’ to ‘char*’

Anyone have any clue on how to fix this?

Comment: The compiler warnings are about the encode function, you do not show how you call the function, therefore we cannot help you more than you compiler allready does. If a functions asks for char* aka char[] you should provide this, not a char.

Comment: You need to post some more details about your problem, and why you think you need to do what you're doing.

Answer (score 1):

Your `ret` function is only returning the first character in the local variable `c`. You want to return a `char*`, and you should never return the address of a local variable, so you will need to create it on the heap.

```
char* ret (const char *bd){
char *c = new char[100];
strcpy(c,bd);
return c;
}

char encode(const char ebuf[],const char epass[]) {
char *buf=ret(ebuf);
char *pass=ret(epass);
```

Comment: the compiler errors provided address the encode function, you are talking about the ret function, but that is another problem indeed. The problem is that the poster is providing 'char' instead 'char*' to the encode function, he/she should show that code.

Comment: The error says "In function ‘char encode(...)’" it has nothing to do with what the OP passed to the encode function. Otherwise the errors would not be on line 36 and 37 (two different lines).